# css/html newbie : issue with image and border (in css)

Tags: html, css, image, border

i'm very new at css/html, i'm trying to use an image on my page, but this code does not work :

it should set the image at the window's width and height with my "100%" but it's just showing the image as is, and for "myclass", i tried to add some text, or not, but it does not show the border.

i followed a tutorial but i don't know where the problem is :

```
body {
        background-image:url("landscape.jpeg");
        background-size:100%;
}

.myclass { position:relative; border:1px solid red; }


<div id="myclass">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Define 'does not work.' What *does* it do (or *not* do)? What did you *expect* it to do?

Comment: @David Thomas : hello, it should set the image at the window's width and height with my "100%" but it's just showing the image as is, and for "myclass", i tried to add some text, or not, but it does not show the border, i'm very new at programming, sorry :) should i set another position or anything like that?

Comment: The path you've supplied for your image suggests that it should be in the same folder as the CSS. Also, are you sure it's `jpeg` (and not `jpg`)?

Comment: @David Thomas : thanks David! i appreciate your help! no, actually the image appears onscreen, but it's not at the width or height of my page, i would like it to be at 100%, is this possible? (ps: how can i change the "-1" ?)

Comment: You can't. The '-1' is from a down-vote because your question, as originally asked, had little information, and 'does not work' is an entirely inadequate problem description. If you mouseover the down-arrow, below the number, you'll see that someone thought that "[this] question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." It was not, I hasten to add, me that down-voted you.

Comment: @David Thomas : oh okay, thanks for the explanation, sorry it was my first post ;-) can you add a +1 for me? i edited my post with some more explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the background image does not show, then the reason is probably that the URL is wrong.

The selector `.myclass` matches no element, as there is no element with class `myclass`. Change `id="myclass"` to `class="myclass"`.

The `background-size` property has limited browser support.

Comment: thanks ! mmh okay i'm getting the point, i did not really understand the thing with class and id. Ok the border works, what about the image? should i use something else to have my image as big as the window? (ps: how can i change this "-1" ?)

Comment: The difference between class and id is; Id is unique(can(should) only be used one time) but classes can be used multiple times. Look at this for more info http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ (the -1 is because someone not like your question, you can not do anything)

Comment: @Miles_Crew: did you manage to specify the image url? otherwise you can try to add the hole url instant.

Comment: @Miles_Crew, you can simulate a 100% background by using a content image instead, putting all the real content in another element, positioning these elements absolutely (with a larger `z-index` value for the content), and setting the image element width to 100%. It will not tile, though.

Comment: @Mattias : thanks ! i think it's ok, i added `100% 100%` with a bigger image, and it works fine! i don't know if it's the best way to do, but it seems to work! thanks for your help!

Comment: @Miles_Crew: here you can read about the CSS3 way of doing it and some more http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ bwt it is a great site for learning ;)